# How to customize the WebSocket data change event subscription in opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I'm learning about OpenDaylight and one point that a read in documentation is about to create a websocket for listen to data change event in the datastore (http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/developer-guide/controller.html#websocket-change-event-notification-subscription-tutorial).

The WebSocket urls that's generated with this tutorial send information about the changes in the datastore, these websocket messages are made in XML and they have a tag called Operation, the operation tag can have three values: Created, Deleted or Update.

My question is if there's a method to create a WebSocket connection for this URL: http://:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes where the connection only sends information that have a Created or Deleted operation tag.

Comment: Why do you want to omit Update notifications? Why not just ignore them?

Comment: It's not a big purpose, i just wondered if i can customize the type of information, filtering by tag for example, that the websocket connection can send, since the connection send a lot of data.

Comment: I understand your point but you know if there's a method for do this?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the WebSocket stuff (never used it) but I would guess there is no such API to filter out operation notifications. TBH - I wouldn't expect there to be - it doesn't seem to make much sense.